# Angular reactive form cannot find control with path

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Currently, I'm creating a reactive form:

```
this.entryService.getEntryObservable(weekNumber).subscribe(entries => {
    this.entriesArr = entries;
    this.entriesReceived = true;
    this.populateEntries();
}, error => {
    this.entriesErrMsg = error;
});

populateEntries() {
    this.entriesForm = this.fb.group({
        entries: this.fb.array(this.entriesArr.map(entry => this.fb.group({
            type: [entry.type, Validators.required],
            hours: [entry.hours, Validators.required],
            tasks: [entry.tasks, Validators.required],
        }, {updateOn: 'blur'})))
    });
}
```

Now I've added a getter which returns the entries:

```
get entries() {
    return (this.entriesForm.get('entries') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

This getter is called inside my HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="entriesForm" *ngIf="entriesReceived">
  <div *ngFor="let entry of entries; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Stunden...</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="number" placeholder="8" min="1" step="1" formControlName="hours">
      <span matSuffix>h</span>
    </mat-form-field>
    .....
  </div>
</form>
```

But somehow I'm getting this error here and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong...

> Error: Cannot find control with path: '4 -> hours'

When I log the entries return value I'm getting this structure in the console:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: How many times does getEntryObservable(weekNumber) emit data? When is that subscription initialized?

Comment: Actually the service returns 5 entries withing the ngOnInit() function! When I log the data I can see them -> updated question.

Comment: So the Observable receives the data once, and there are 5 items in the array, right?

Comment: @alcfeoh Thats correct! Only once!

Comment: Shouldn't your ngFor iterate over entriesArr rather than entries?

Comment: @alcfeoh Would be another possible solution, but I've learned that this is the correct way and Angular fills out the form by the controls - am I wrong?

Comment: The way your code is written, it is possible that the getter is called before the array is initialized. I would move 'this.entriesReceived = true;' to after 'this.populateEntries()'

Comment: @alcfeoh I've tried that one out without any success :/

Comment: Your screenshot is showing form group `0`, while the error is occurring at form group `4`. How does the `FormGroup` object look at index `4`?

Comment: @JoshuaMcCarthy all indexes are failing. Just posted one of them. Do you need every error from every index?

Comment: No need for every index. Was just checking as index `4` was the only one you quoted in your question.